# Supose A is linearly independent with A = $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$, then every $B$ with $B = \{u_1,...u_m\}$ with $m < n$ does not span $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We work in (R,V,+), suppose A is linearly independent with $A =\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$, then every $B$ with $B = \{u_1,...u_m\}$ with $m < n$ does not span $V$. I don't really know how to prove this, is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Hint: Given there are $n$ linearly independent vectors, what can you say about the number of vectors required to span $V$?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

If there are $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$, then $\operatorname {dim}V\ge n$.

Now if $\{u_1,\dots, u_m\}$ span $V$, then $\operatorname {dim}V\le m$.

This is a contradiction,  since $m\lt n$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what (R,V,+) means, but I assume you mean that $V$ is a vector space over the field of real numbers $\Bbb{R}$. Consider $2$ cases:

*Case $1$:* $\dim(V) = \infty$.

In this case, by definition, $V$ does not have a finite spanning set. Hence, $B$ does not span $V$.

*Case $2$:* $\dim(V) < \infty$.

I hope you note that in general, if a subset $S \subset V$ has $k$ elements, then $\dim \text{span}(S) \leq k$, with equality if and only if $S$ is linearly independent. With this, we get the following:
\begin{align}
\dim \text{span}(B) &\leq m \\
&< n \\
&= \dim \text{span}(A) \\
&\leq \dim V
\end{align}
So, $\dim \text{span}(B) < \dim V$, hence $\text{span}(B) \neq V$.

---

Although the statements I made above are true, I'd highly suggest you consult a proper linear algebra textbook, because the question you asked is a foundational/elementary result. As such what can happen is that we (on stackexchange) might assume more than you actually know when giving an answer, so it may not be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly in the beginning of my book ;), I had yet proved the contraposition, but I was asking myself wether it was possible to do it directly ;)